# TypeError when trying to "repo init" on Python 3.3

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, repository

I have Arch Linux
Python 3.3.0
I've downloaded the latest repo, and if i try to do the repo init from the Google example, i get this error:

```
 [username@otp-username-l2 teste]$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/username/bin/repo", line 738, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/home/username/bin/repo", line 705, in main
_Init(args)
 File "/home/username/bin/repo", line 234, in _Init
_CheckGitVersion()
 File "/home/username/bin/repo", line 274, in _CheckGitVersion
if not ver_str.startswith('git version '):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

The reason for which i am forced to do a new repo init is that i must do a commit from an already initialized repo, but i've changed the git user from everywhere, and i still get this:

```
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 966 bytes, done.
Total 12 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
o ssh://new.username@128.224.0.74:29418/stelvio/mm
![remote rejected] branchname -> refs/for/main_dev (you are not committer  oldusername@email.com)
 error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://new.username@128.224.0.74:29418/project/one'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Repo does not yet fully support Python 3. Some work has been done, such as [using the `print` function](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/cecd1d864fc3cf02cf50d367111e0d0e173c5dc6) and [importing the correct urllib](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/1f7627fd3ccab0fbab88ad2d082b67f5719af92c), but that work doesn't appear to have been finished.

For now, you'll need to use it with Python 2. You could edit the shebang at the top of the `repo` executable by replacing `python` with `python2` or you could run:

```
python2 `which repo`
```

assuming you have a version of Python 2 installed in your path as `python2`.

You can easily reproduce the problem:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Nov  7 2012, 19:36:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b'asd'.startswith('asd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

And here is the relevent code of `_CheckGitVersion()`:

```
def _CheckGitVersion():
  cmd = [GIT, '--version']
  try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

   ...

  ver_str = proc.stdout.read().strip()
  proc.stdout.close()
  proc.wait()

  if not ver_str.startswith('git version '):
```

`read`ing the `stdout` of the `Popen` call returns `bytes`, and so what is passed to `startswith` has to also be `bytes` (raw bytes of data) rather than `str` (a sequence of Unicode code points).

Comment: @Cumatru If you're getting the same error, you're still running it with Python 3. If it's a different error, post the details.

Comment: Although it's very old thread, however can anyone confirm that the current repo launcher version 2.30 supported by python3 or not? @agf

Comment: @santoshverma Yes, it's Python 3.

Answer (score 8):

Just stumbled upon this error while trying to revive my P990.

The first fix is to modify the repo command (in ~/bin in your case, otherwise check which repo to find where it is) and change the first line from

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

This allows you to repo init, but you will run into the message klauspeter mentioned:

```
error: Python 3 support is not fully implemented in repo yet.
Please use Python 2.6 - 2.7 instead.
```

I wouldn't recommend changing the system-wide symlink. Instead, navigate into the newly created .repo folder.

If you started repo init in $basedir, you want to check $basedir/.repo/repo. Inside you'll find a local repo installation, again having a shebang with plain 'python' (we want python2).

So edit all files containing that line (**main.py, repo and wrapper.py**) according to the first steps above and you're good to go. For me repo now even asked me to update my global installation (that is, copying $basedir/.repo/repo/repo to ~/bin), which you're free to do (that version is 'fixed' now).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, agf's solutions made the repo-script work, but it still exited stating that it won't work with python 3:

> error: Python 3 support is not fully implemented in repo yet.
>   Please use Python 2.6 - 2.7 instead.

The (admittedly rather dirty) way around this for me was to change the symlink for the python bin from python3 to python2.

Remember to revert this once you're done!

Comment: This is a horrible solution.