# AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'extend' - repo sync

Tags: python, linux, git, repo

I am trying to run repo init and repo sync commands and having trouble with them as detailed below:

```
repo init -u <git-url> -b release -m <manifest-xml> --repo-url=<url> --repo-branch=<branch>
```

I was getting the following error

```
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'
```

but then I followed these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63125058/12497236) and was able to get it to work but then `repo sync` fails now

```
repo sync

warning: Python 3 support is currently experimental. YMMV.
Please use Python 2.6 - 2.7 instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tmp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 500, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/tmp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 476, in _Main
    result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
  File "/home/tmp/.repo/repo/main.py", line 155, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "/home//tmp/.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py", line 624, in Execute
    submodules_ok=opt.fetch_submodules)
  File "/home/tmp/.repo/repo/command.py", line 148, in GetProjects
    all_projects_list.extend(derived_projects.values())
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

Is it implying I need to use python 2 now? I thought repo version 1.22 would require python 3.6+

Is [this a safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19314433/12497236) solution?

I even tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7237949/12497236) to no avail

Comment: Did you read the warning? `warning: Python 3 support is currently experimental. YMMV.`

Comment: Yes, but `python -V` is 2.7.12

Comment: While `python -V` may report 2.7.12, the version of python that `repo` is getting is 3.something. You might want to figure out why that is the case and fix that first. (It seems odd that the virtualenv trick did not work - that's how I normally deal with these Python version issues myself, and it works fine for me in multiple OSes.)

Comment: it's weird because I had to upgrade to python 3.6 for the initial `repo init` command to work, and now `repo sync` seemingly requires python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same `repo sync` issue. However, for my case the scenario was quite specific, since I have already had the source tree checked out initially and then just wanted to make sure that it is up to date by running `repo sync`.
It seems the problem for my case was the repo tool upgrade that I performed in between the initial and problematic `repo sync`. There seems to be some incompatibility that blocked me from updating the already checked out tree. Fortunately, initializing new source tree and `repo sync`-ing it from scratch worked fine.